# How can I skip cells that span multiple rows in excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel, loops

So I have a for loop that goes like this..:

```
for (int i = 12; i < 200; i++)
{
    //Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(sheet01.Cells[12, 2].Value2));
    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheet01.Cells[i, 2].Value2)) && sheet01.Cells[i, 2].Value2.Length == 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sheet01.Name);
        hcnNumber.Add(Convert.ToString(sheet01.Cells[i, 2].Value2));
    }
}
```

This code encounters an error whenever the cell [i,2] when i spans more than one column.

How can I skip rows rows that span more than one column ?

so something if row.length > 1

Thanks

Comment: I could not find anything similar online for this question. I am looking for an if statement that can detect if a cell number spans > 1 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to work on your requirement on my local system. If I understand your requirement, You need to show only those rows where only 1st column has value, If for example a row has 10 column of which either all or more than 1 column contains data, needs to be skipped. I think it should help you a bit to reach your goal.
Below is the code which loops through and gives you the expected result.

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\acn\Desktop\CopyofFinancialSample.xlsx");
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;


        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {

                //add useful things here!   
                if (j != 1)
                {
                    if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }

            }
            if (count > 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                if (xlRange.Cells[i, 1] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2 != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
            }
        }
```

And if you need the complete console program to test the req, Please find below

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        //Create COM Objects. Create a COM object for everything that is referenced
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\acn\Desktop\CopyofFinancialSample.xlsx");
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;


        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {

                //add useful things here!   
                if (j != 1)
                {
                    if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }

            }
            if (count > 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                if (xlRange.Cells[i, 1] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2 != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
            }
        }
        //cleanup
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        //rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
        //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
        //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

        //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

        //close and release
        xlWorkbook.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

        //quit and release
        xlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
         Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```